# auto completion in zsh on 3rd parameter

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I have a shell script it's usage is:

```
foo.sh <name> <type> <*.tar.gz>
```

I want to setup a  complete on 3rd parameter only.
If I press  on 1st parameter, just show the usage.

Could I use zsh's zshcomp to do this job?

for example:

```
foo.sh <tab>  # display usage
foo.sh a b <tab> # show files match with *.tar.gz
```

Is there similar script which I could follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Things to read.

Here is a blog post discussing the [Z-Shell Completion System](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2012/003/).

For a slightly more in-depth discussion, read [this unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33255/how-to-define-and-load-your-own-shell-function-in-zsh) answer.

And, as always, [read the man pages!](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshcompsys).

Edit: Forgot to add: `echo $fpath` will show you the function path that `zsh` uses. On OSX, I have: `/usr/local/share/zsh/4.3.17/functions`, (location may vary for you), which contains **all the ZSH completion functions**. Have a look at `_ssh`, `_ls`, `_tar` etc - they're all there, and they all have *lots* of nifty features you can learn from.

---

#### Addressing the question: the direction you should go.

What you're asking is achievable, though. There are several steps.

1. You need to write a z-shell completion function. It needs to be located on the `fpath`; the function-path that `zsh` uses for it's completion system functions. (If it's a small function, putting it into `~/.zshrc` will also work, but isn't recommended).
2. You want completion on the 3rd parameter. To do that, your function would look something like the following:

   ```
   _arguments "3:<MENU>:<COMPLETION>"
   ```

   `<MENU>` is the *menu description*, which you'll see if you've enabled the menu descriptions. (That's done using `zstyle`; read the man pages, or the linked pages, for more information). 
   `<COMPLETION>` is the things that you can complete with. For example, if you used:

   ```
   _arguments "3::(Foo Bar)"
   ```

   when you ran your script and pressed `<TAB>`, you'd have the option of either `Foo` or `Bar`. 
   [NOTE: There is no `<MENU>` in that example. If you don't want a menu descriptor, you can omit it as shown].
3. You want completion on `*.tar` files. You can call `_files` to do that:

   ```
   _files -g \*.tar
   ```
4. Show usage on first parameter: that'd be a completion with no arguments (ie, argument 1). I'm not sure why you'd want completion on only the third option but not the first two (typical usage descriptions), so I don't know how to answer this. If your script is supposed to be used like this: `script foo bar FILE.tar`, wouldn't you want to complete the `foo` and `bar` arguments as well?
   Perhaps a better solution would be displaying the usage when the script is run without parameters.

Full script would look something like the following:

```
#compdef myscript

_arguments "3:tar files:_files -g \*.tar"
```

Comment: Please notice that for me `_arguments "3::(Foo Bar)"` doesn't work. It should have space between colons i.e. `_arguments "3: :(Foo Bar)"`.