# How can I autocomplete each parameter in a different way?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a function called load_pg, which is defined like this:

```
load_pg () {
    pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U $1 -d $2 $3
}
```

And I'm trying to autocomplete each parameter, with the following code:

```
#compdef load_pg
_arguments -s \
  "1::_ldpguser" \
  "2::_ldpgdb" \
  "3::_ldpgfile"

_ldpguser () {
  compadd $USER
}

_ldpgdb () {
  compadd $(cat config/database.yml | grep -i database | awk '{print $2}')
}

_ldpgfile () {
  compadd $(ls *.dump*)
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I press TAB. What am I doing wrong? I tried using code from the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194558/auto-completion-in-zsh-on-3rd-parameter)

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that `$USER` is not defined. Using an almost blank `~/.zshrc` with your functions, TAB does nothing - if I define `USER="foobar"`, TAB will complete to: `load_pg foobar cat: config/database.yml: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Also note that unless you autoload `_ldpg{user,db,file}`, they're not known when `_arguments` tries to call them - I'd put those function definitions above the call to `_arguments`. If that's not enough to help, let me know and I'll have a proper whack to get a solution for you.

Comment: You can try `functions -t _ldpguser` to trace the execution of the function. That should help you determine what's going wrong.